# How to initialise an image from a canvas?

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas

Assume I have a an image and a canvas. I use the canvas api to modify the displayed image.

I now need to have 2 copies of the image, the original and the modified one.

the pseudo code to convey what I am trying to do would be:

```
var img = fetchImage();

context.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100);

var copy = context.getImage();
```

I have tried searching it up but I don't find an answer to this.

Edit:

By "initialise", I mean creating a deep copy of an image. So, the original image has no line, the modified image in the canvas has a line, I now need 2 independent images, one with the line and one without.

Comment: It's unclear what you exactly mean by "initialise an image"

Comment: Edited for clarity, hope it;s non ambigous now

Comment: Take a look at [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)

Comment: That allows me to draw an image onto the canvas, but what I need is to draw the canvas onto the image

Comment: It doesn't really matter what on what) Once you drawn an image on canvas, you may add any extra drawing (like line) on it.

Comment: I know, but after I have done all those modifications I need to fetch them back. I.e I need the result contained onto the same object tyoe as the original image.

Comment: _I need the result contained onto the same object tyoe as the original image._ Then you're looking for [`toDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL). Note that it also implies server-side processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an image out of a drawn canvas with the [`getImageData` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData).

Or perhaps even [`toDataURL` might be of help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL).

Comment: getImageData seems to be what I want, how do I initialise an image (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) from the returned ImageData object?

Comment: you can set the `.src` attribute on an `image` object, and then invoke `canvas.drawImage` with the image object.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with image data URL's, try this snippet

```js
  let imageDataUrl = 'data:image/png;base64,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';

  let image = document.querySelector('img');
  image.src = imageDataUrl;

  let canvas;

  image.addEventListener('load', () => {
    canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

    let margin = 10;
    context.strokeRect(margin, margin, canvas.width - margin * 2, canvas.height - margin * 2);

    console.log('new data url:', canvas.toDataURL());
  });
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2019/us-teacher-appreciation-week-2019-begins-4994791740801024-l.png">
</div>

<div>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```